# Splunk : How to sum the values of the fields that are a result of if condition

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

My Aim :

This below query gives me count of success, failure by b_key. I want to now get the sum of all success and failures as shown in the image below. Also I want to count the number of b_key for which the failure occured. In the example below it will be 2.

[image]

**Query :**

```
| stats dc(test_events) as events by a_key,b_key
| eval status = if(events=2,"Success","Failure") 
| chart count over b_key by status
```

Comment: Can you do a `sum(status)` before the `count` within the `chart` to get the desired result?

Comment: Is a "device guid" the same as b_key or a different field?  If different, which one?

Comment: @YoshiMbele that adds both the success and failure for each b_key. I want the sum for both status separately

Comment: @RichG It is same as b_key. My bad. Corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `addcoltotals` command to create the "Sum" field.

```
| stats dc(test_events) as events by a_key,b_key
| eval status = if(events=2,"Success","Failure") 
| chart count over b_key by status
| addcoltotals labelfield=b_key label="Sum"
```

Comment: That sounded so simple. Thanks @RichG. Could you please also help me with my second query? 'count the number of b_key for which the failure occurred, basically I want to get the count of unique b_key on which the failures occurred'

Comment: Also I want to understand if I want to use the sum values of Success and Failure how can I reference them? Simply referencing them by Success, Failure is not working. I want to know the success % = Success/Sum(Success)*100

Comment: The problem with getting a count of distinct b_key values is the values were discarded by the `stats` command.

Comment: One cannot access a specific row of results.  Commands apply to all rows. To get the % success, use `eval`, but it will be added to all rows.